# Erro ao tentar conectar via ODBC ao MySQL

Tags: mysql, odbc

Estou tentando realizar uma conexão via ODBC com o **Banco de Dados MySQL** para acessar dados no Excel, porém após realizar todas as configurações necessárias a seguinte janela de erro me é mostrada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configurei assim o conector:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se tiverem alguma ideia de o que pode estar causando tal erro, ou o que seria necessário alterar na configuração

Comment: Na primeira imagem é indicado que o usuário **reports** não tem acesso. Já verificou se ele existe no banco?

Comment: @ismael Sim, o usuário **reports** existe no banco

Comment: Já fez o `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES`?

Comment: @ismael Não fiz, o que seria isso? Como posso executá-lo?

Comment: Embora o usuário reports esteja criado, é necessário conceder-lhe as permissões necessárias para acesso remoto. Vou postar uma resposta com este comando.

Comment: @Bacco Por que duplicata se minha questão não envolve PHP e sim ODBC?

Comment: Pq o ODBC é irrelevante para a questão, assim como o PHP na outra. O problema é só de MySQL. Se tentar acessar diretamente(sem ODBC) vai ter o mesmo problema. Note que inclusive, as respostas são a mesma coisa nos 2 casos. Precisa autorizar seu usuário no MySQL, seja com o comando GRANT, ou com algum utilitário como o MySQL Workbech, ou o MySQL Database Administrator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acesse o Servidor como root

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost
```

E conceda o privilégio ao usuário

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'reports'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sua senha';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

[Sintaxe GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/grant.html)

### Melhores práticas

Procure não conceder TODOS os privilégios em todos os bancos, o root já tem essa função.
Especifique o que este usuário poderá ter acesso. Exemplo:

```
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON <seu_banco>.* TO 'reports'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sua_senha';
```

Comment: Onde eu posso conceder tal privilégio? Eu tenho em minha estação de trabalho o *MySQL Workbench* instalado para acessar o banco porém tal erro também ocorre quando tento acessar o banco daqui, então por onde posso realizar tal comando?

Comment: Está utilizando SO Windows ou Linux? Você conseguiu logar como root? Coloquei na resposta o caminho por prompt de comando. É necessário logar como root pq ele PODE rodar o comando GRANT.

Comment: Estou utilizando Windows, mas mesmo tendo privilégio de administrador quando executo o comando no prompt ele me retorna que o comando GRANT não é reconhecido  como um comando interno

Comment: @R.Santos Você consegue executar um select simples? Ou ainda um comando como `SHOW GRANTS FOR reports`?

Comment: Eu não estou conseguindo conectar ao Banco, vou pedir para a equipe de rede verificar a questão de liberação do acesso, te dou retorno quando tiver uma resposta